# Define two functions next to each other

Tags: horizontal-alignment, alignment

I want to define the following two functions:

```
\begin{align*}
    f_a:\mathbb{Q}[x,y]&\longrightarrow R_a\\
    x&\longmapsto x\\
    y&\longmapsto y\\
    xy&\longmapsto 0\\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    f_b:\mathbb{Q}[x,y]&\longrightarrow R_b\\
    x&\longmapsto (x,x,x,\ldots)\\
    y&\longmapsto (y,y,y,\ldots)\\
    xy&\longmapsto (0,xy,xy,\ldots)\\
\end{align*}
```

However, rather than one being on top of the other, I would like them to be next to eachother. How can I do that?

**Edit**: I've tried using the gather environment, unsuccessfully

Comment: Have a look at the `minipage` environment.

Comment: Off-topic: I think you should use `\colon` rather than `:` after `f_a` and `f_b`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rewrite this in one `align*` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
f_a:\mathbb{Q}[x,y] & \longrightarrow R_a
     &  f_b:\mathbb{Q}[x,y] & \longrightarrow R_b\\
%
x & \longmapsto x
    &   x & \longmapsto (x,x,x,\ldots)\\
%
y & \longmapsto y\
    &   y & \longmapsto (y,y,y,\ldots)\\  
%
xy & \longmapsto 0
    &   xy & \longmapsto (0,xy,xy,\ldots)\\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If the corresponding lines have the same height, it's simpler to use two `aligned` environments

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}[t]
    f_a:\mathbb{Q}[x,y]&\rightarrow R_a \\
    x&\mapsto x \\
    y&\mapsto y \\
    xy&\mapsto 0
\end{aligned}
\qquad\qquad
\begin{aligned}[t]
    f_b:\mathbb{Q}[x,y]&\rightarrow R_b \\
    x&\mapsto (x,x,x,\dotsc) \\
    y&\mapsto (y,y,y,\dotsc) \\
    xy&\mapsto (0,xy,xy,\dotsc)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

I removed all `long`, but you're free to reinsert them (after observing that the output with them is not really nice). Note, however, `\dotsc` instead of `\ldots`. I'd use `\colon` instead of `:` but it's a stylistic decision you have to make.

[image]

If your corresponding lines might have different heights, use a single `alignedat` environment (with a more complicated input, though).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
  f_a:\mathbb{Q}[x,y]&\rightarrow R_a
  &\qquad\qquad
  f_b:\mathbb{Q}[x,y]&\rightarrow R_b \\
  x&\mapsto x &  x&\mapsto (x,x,x,\dotsc) \\
  y&\mapsto y &  y&\mapsto (y,y,y,\dotsc) \\
 xy&\mapsto 0 & xy&\mapsto (0,xy,xy,\dotsc)
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Hope this is useful for you, please excuse, if not.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,multicol}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{align*}
    f_a:\mathbb{Q}[x,y]&\longrightarrow R_a\\
    x&\longmapsto x\\
    y&\longmapsto y\\
    xy&\longmapsto 0\\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    f_b:\mathbb{Q}[x,y]&\longrightarrow R_b\\
    x&\longmapsto (x,x,x,\ldots)\\
    y&\longmapsto (y,y,y,\ldots)\\
    xy&\longmapsto (0,xy,xy,\ldots)\\
\end{align*}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I think I will stick to the other answer because this one doesn't aligb the text properly, however.

Comment: @kubo Yes, `Zarko's` answer better than mine